# An impulse is given to a sphere out of the center?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

I'm wondering what will happen if there is an impulse $J$ given to a sphere mass $M$ out of its center?
I'm sure that it will rotate about the center, but what is its translational motion? It will move with the speed $J/M$ with the center, or with the point where the impulse is given??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impulse is the change in total momentum of the body of mass. The momentum $P$ of a rigid body is the product of the velocity of the centre of mass $v$ and total mass $M$.

A free rigid body's centre of mass translates at constant velocity, while the body itself performs a rotation about the centre of mass.

Thus, after the impulse $J$ has been applied, the centre of mass translates at $v=J/M$ while, depending on where and how the force is applied, the body will also have acquired angular momentum $L$.